# Django - get list of failed sent mails via Postfix

Tags: python, django, postfix-mta

Using django's `EmailMultiAlternatives` to send email via Postfix, I need to know the list of deferred messages.

I've tried to get that information using `mailq` but the problem was that I didn't have the message id generated by Postfix. For example `31C2D10A9F93` in this result:

```
31C2D10A9F93     8462 Sat Jan 17 09:51:10  noreply@foo.bar
                (connect to gmeil.com[111.111.111.111]:25: Connection refused)
                                         mr_xyzx@gmeil.com
```

Is there any way to find the list of failed sent message? or
any API to retrieve that ID from Postfix when the `send` method is called?

Note that, maybe it has sent many mail to a same person, so it cannot use the email address from that result text.